# Delphi incompatible types

Tags: delphi

I have a really strange bug, I tried to restart my IDE but it didn't fixed it.

I've created a interface that looks like this:

```
myInterface = interface
 ['{delphi guid key here}'] (CTRL+ALT+G)
 function getDataPCE : IDataPCE;
 property dataPCE : IDataPCE read getDataPCE;
 (some other properties that works)
end;
```

Then i created my object that inherits from this interface of course

```
myObject = class(TInterfacedObject, myInterface)
 private
  ... 
  function getDataPCE : IDataPCE;
  ...
 public
  ...
  property dataPCE : IDataPCE read getDataPCE;
  ...
 end;
```

the "..." means there some other properties and functions but not related to this.

And I'm getting this error: "Incompatible types"

How can I solve this?

EDIT

```
    IInfoNotisReservation = interface
      ['{AE5CEC31-B2CE-4A3D-9CFE-6393646E4A04}']

      function getNumberPCE : String;
      function getDataPCE(numRegister : String; numPCEFormated : String): IRioPiece;
      procedure setNumberPCE(NumberPCE: String);
      function getRegName : String;
      procedure setRegName(RegName: String);
      function getRegKey : String;
      procedure setRegKey(RegKey: String);

      property NumberPCE : String read getNumberPCE write setNumberPCE;
      property RegName : String read getRegName write setRegName;
      property RegKey : String read getRegKey write setRegKey;
      property DataPCE : IRioPiece read getDataPCE;
    end;

type
  TInfoNotisReservation = class(TInterfacedObject, IInfoNotisReservation)

  private
    DataBase  : IDataBase;
    SuperRio  : ISuperRio;
    RioN      : IRio;
    fPCENum    : String;

    function getDataPCE(numRegister : String; numPCEFormated : String): IRioPiece;
    function getNumberPCE: string;
    function getRegKey: string;
    function getRegName: string;
    procedure setNumberPCE(NumberPCE: string);
    procedure setRegKey(RegKey: string);
    procedure setRegName(RegName: string);
    procedure setRioN(Registre: string);
  public
    Constructor Create;
    property DataPCE : IRioPiece read getDataPCE;
    property NumberPCE : String read getNumberPCE write setNumberPCE;
    property RegName : String read getRegName write setRegName;
    property RegKey : String read getRegKey write setRegKey;

end;

function TInfoNotisReservation.getDataPCE(numRegister,
  numPCEFormated: String): IRioPiece;
begin
  setRioN(numRegister);
  Result := RioN.GetPieceByID(RioN.PieceNumberToID(NumPCEFormated).Item[0].ID, FLAG_IGNORE_SECURITY);
end;
```

Comment: The code in the question compiles fine. Please present an MCVE that demonstrates your problem. As it stands, this question will be closed as off topic because the code in the question does not demonstrate the problem that you report.

Comment: What do you want exactly? I don't get why it says incomptabiles types. Here you have everything i use for this implementation...

Comment: Please present an MCVE that demonstrates the problem. The code in the question does not produce the error that you report. Oh, and another thing. Always report error messages verbatim, and always indicate the line on which they occur.

Comment: My IDE indicates the problem occurs in my Interface declaration at the line of the property. It highlights "property DataPCE: IDataPCE read getDataPCE;" with the messages Incompatible types. And as you can see, my getDataPCE returns the same type

Comment: Please present an MCVE that demonstrates the problem. The code in the question does not produce the error that you report.

Comment: What do you want me to do? ^^ The problem is in my interface and you have the intterface here. There's no code in an interface, there just the declaration of properties and functions that's all.

Comment: Post all the code, most likely the problem is not from the code you are showing us.

Comment: For a start I'd like you to read carefully the comments that I have repeatedly written that state that the code in the question does not produce the error that you report.

Comment: @CiucaS No, we don't want all of the code. We just want enough code to demonstrate the problem. So we want the code to be cut down to a minimal reproduction. But we also want code that compiles.

Comment: Here you have the code. The IDE says the problem is in my interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of helping you understand how to ask a question, here is the MCVE that you should have submitted.

```
type
  IRioPiece = interface
  end;

  IInfoNotisReservation = interface
    ['{AE5CEC31-B2CE-4A3D-9CFE-6393646E4A04}']
    function getDataPCE(numRegister: String; numPCEFormated: String): IRioPiece;
    property dataPCE: IRioPiece read getDataPCE; // ERROR HERE
  end;

begin
end.
```

This results in this error:

> [dcc32 Error] E2008 Incompatible types

The reason is that a property getter for a property of type `IRioPiece` must be a function that accepts no parameters and has return type of `IRioPiece`. But your getter function requires two arguments, and they need to come from somewhere. As written above, these arguments are not supplied when you access the property.

So you could fix the compilation error by changing the declaration of `getDataPCE` to:

```
function getDataPCE: IRioPiece;
```

But that's almost certainly the wrong solution. Presumably you declared those parameters to `getDataPCE` because you need to supply them. In which case you cannot remove them. Which means that you cannot declare a simple property `dataPCE` that is backed by `getDataPCE`. My guess is that you simply need to remove the `dataPCE` property.

Of course, you could declare an [array property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Array_Properties) like this:

```
property dataPCE[numRegister: String; numPCEFormated: String]: IRioPiece 
  read getDataPCE;
```

Which would mean you access the property like this:

```
dataPCE := resvervation.dataPCE[numRegister, numPCEFormatted];
```

But to me that is stretching the use of a property too far. I think it is better to access this using a function.

**Conclusion**

Remove the `dataPCE` property and have consumers of the interface call `getDataPCE` instead.

Comment: But i need those parameters

Comment: Indeed you do. Which means that a property is not appropriate.

Comment: yeah ok, so it works but kinda strange it doesn't work with a property. I removed it and put the function in public declaration so it will work like that but yeah.. :/ Thanks for helping

Comment: Why is it strange. `getDataPCE` requires two arguments. If you attempt to access a non-indexed property, where are those arguments going to come from?

Comment: It does not work with that property because the property call is translated into a function call behind the scenes. Which leaves us with the question, what the compiler should pass as function arguments, since you don't provide them via property call. And that's what the "incompatible types" message is trying to tell you. To implement the property properly, there is also a [`property[]` Syntax available (see docs)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Properties). It is a bit awkward in my opinion, but it works perfectly.

Comment: FWIW, what I hope most is that you look closely at the MCVE in this answer. I hope that you take on board the importance of producing minimal code that demonstrates a problem. If you had done so I think it likely that you would have spotted the problem for yourself.

Comment: @JensG Not all functions should be converted into properties

Comment: oh ok now i get the problem, that's so obvious gosh >_> i need to face palm so hard now...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sure, but it's a free country and technically possible. :-) That's why I said "awkward"